# javascript date subtract hours - Error

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to subtract 1 hour from the current date,  I'm using this code:

```
var date = new Date();
// date is **Fri Apr 03 2015 16:47:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)**
var uploadDateFilter = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours()-1)).toISOString();
//now date is **Fri Apr 03 2015 14:47:33 GMT+0100 (GMT Standard Time)**
```

There's less two hours instead of just one. What am I missing here?

Comment: You're printing different things. Try `date.toISOString()`.

Comment: And generally, if you're asking if something really basic is a bug in one of the world's most popular programming languages, the answer is almost always "no".

Comment: Works when looking at the elements in the same format ... http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/5nma5uhr/

Comment: @rfornal please post you comment and code as answer and I'll accept it as the correct answer. thank you.

Comment: @PedroLobito Appreciate it ...

Comment: @Juhana do you know why `date.toISOString()` returns 1 hour less than simply `date` ?

Comment: @PedroLobito Because it returns the UTC time which is 1 hour behind your local time.

Comment: @Juhana, tks, but why does `date` always returns UTC instead of the local machine time?

Comment: No, `.toISOString()` returns UTC. Printing the Date object as is shows local time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works when looking at the elements in the same format.

```
<div class="original"></div>
<div class="updated"></div>
```

Using jQuery to post the information ... with your code, as is.

```
$(".original").text(date.toISOString());
$(".updated").text(uploadDateFilter);
```

Results in ...

```
2015-04-03T16:00:23.441Z
2015-04-03T15:00:23.441Z
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rfornal/5nma5uhr/

Comment: do you know why date **without** `toISOString()` returns the correct time of my computer and date **with** `toISOString()` one hour less ?

Comment: `toISOString()` uses a timezone that is always zero UTC offset.  Without it, you are using local time (timezone).  This can also be affected by Daylight Savings Time in some locations.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need .toISOString(), but for me it works :

```
var date = new Date();
var uploadDateFilter = new Date(new Date(date).setHours(date.getHours()-1));
console.log(date);
console.log(uploadDateFilter);
```

Console output :

```
Fri, 03 Apr 2015 15:59:48 GMT
Fri, 03 Apr 2015 14:59:48 GMT
```

http://repl.it/gxL

Answer (score 0):

The reason appears to be daylight saving [check this my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8xg5n656/).

For me in the UK the clocks went forward on Mar 29, 2015. Checking the effect of `new Date().toISOString()` before and after this date, during daylight saving the result is one hour less.